# See many Tombstone Warnings

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

New in operating cassandra clusters. Having a 1 DC and 14 node production cluster running @ DCE v.2.1.15.

System log shows many TS warnings like below and are wondering if this is okay or due to the applications natur vs too low (default TS warn level=5000) or if we ought to run manual compactions between our nightly repairs (every node gets repaired once @ week), raise TS warn level...

Hints appreciated!

> WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2016-08-18 11:45:02,536
>   SliceQueryFilter.java:320 - Read 0 live and 6251 tombstone cells in
>   KeyspaceMetadata.CF_RecentIndex for key: 3230303230305febd8fc98e0bf11e
>   5b870502699f4d249 (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 5000 columns were
>   requested, slices=[-] WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-3] 2016-08-18
>   11:45:02,548 SliceQueryFilter.java:320 - Read 0 live and 6251
>   tombstone cells in KeyspaceMetadata.CF_MessageFlagsIndex for key:
>   3230303230305febd8fc98e 0bf11e5b870502699f4d249 (see
>   tombstone_warn_threshold). 1 columns were requested, slices=[1-1:!]
>   WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2016-08-18 11:45:04,566
>   SliceQueryFilter.java:320 - Read 1 live and 1123 tombstone cells in
>   KeyspaceMetadata.CF_UIDIndex for key: 3230303230315f299f8d3ae0c011e593
>   3d7775140b84c3 (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 5000 columns were
>   requested, slices=[-] WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2016-08-18
>   11:45:11,853 SliceQueryFilter.java:320 - Read 0 live and 6251
>   tombstone cells in KeyspaceMetadata.CF_RecentIndex for key:
>   3230303230305febd8fc98e0bf11e 5b870502699f4d249 (see
>   tombstone_warn_threshold). 5000 columns were requested, slices=[-]
>   WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2016-08-18 11:45:11,864
>   SliceQueryFilter.java:320 - Read 0 live and 6251 tombstone cells in
>   KeyspaceMetadata.CF_MessageFlagsIndex for key: 3230303230305febd8fc98e
>   0bf11e5b870502699f4d249 (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 1 columns were
>   requested, slices=[1-1:!] WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2016-08-18
>   11:46:09,624 SliceQueryFilter.java:320 - Read 2 live and 2537
>   tombstone cells in KeyspaceMetadata.CF_TimeIndex for key:
>   3230303030385ffebcbd200d9411e6b 9750c94c36d1038 (see
>   tombstone_warn_threshold). 5000 columns were requested, slices=[-]
>   WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-3] 2016-08-18 11:47:31,434
>   SliceQueryFilter.java:320 - Read 2 live and 2544 tombstone cells in
>   KeyspaceMetadata.CF_TimeIndex for key: 3230303030345f6b87b24afbe111e5b
>   f7f828e02f15dd6 (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 5000 columns were
>   requested, slices=[-] WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2016-08-18
>   11:49:13,870 SliceQueryFilter.java:320 - Read 3 live and 2540
>   tombstone cells in KeyspaceMetadata.CF_TimeIndex for key:
>   3230303030355f533d997cfbdf11e59 85390948f56b8a7 (see
>   tombstone_warn_threshold). 5000 columns were requested, slices=[-]

Answer (score 0):

Hai steffen please go through your opscenter and see how many tables have Ts more than 5000 if the no.of tables are less, running manually compactions on those particular tables will be a good solution , as you mentioned you are repairing once a week i would suggest to check the data model of the keyspace why it is causing high no.of TS. 
  If you are not using Opscenter you can check no.of tombstones
           sstable2json full_path | grep \"t\"| wc -l

Comment: Thanks, will do ... (do have OpsCenter... still, migrating metrics monitoring to ELK/G :)

Comment: BTW it's a vendor supplied Application and Datamodel, which they had DataStax in over initially, so...

Comment: Where can TS be seen in OpsC? Thought it might have been a TBL metric, guess not...

Comment: i use dse enterprise in opscenter --> services --> Best Practice services --> Performance Service - Table Metrics Advisor --> Tombstone count Turn rule On, i am not aware if it is in Community addition or not. One more thing you can do in enable tracing ON in Cqlsh and consistency all run queries on tables where you see warn in logs you will get to know no.of tombstones are read for a query which will impact you latencies, you can also decrease gc_grace_period.

Comment: These link below may help you to understand how tombstones will distributed across the cluster                                                          http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/tombstones-and-compaction-48960191 http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3JSW_5.2.0/com.ibm.help.gdha_tuning.doc/com.ibm.help.gdha_tuning.doc/gdha_configuring_gc_grace_seconds.html